# Problem with *NgFor in angular: "Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Im working on a website that is based in angular with a connection to a sql server. I'm trying to generate a table on the homepage of the website, but currently I can't figure out why its not working.

error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays.

the rooms$ are observable array of objects, with the current data set having only 1 object.
the NgFor cant iterate through it, despite being async, why?

homecomponent.html:

```
<body class="main" style="max-height: 50%">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>Debate Time</th>
    <th>User's Stance</th>
    <th>Join</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let room of rooms$ | async">
    <td>{{ room.creator }}</td>
    <td>{{ room.topic }}</td>
    <td width=200px>{{ room.timeO }}</td>
    <td width=300px>{{ room.stance }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

homecomponent.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import { RoomService } from "../services/room.service";
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';


import { Room } from "src/app/models/Room";
import { User } from "src/app/models/User";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  isAuthenticated = false;
  rooms$: Observable<Room[]>;
  userId: Pick<User, "id">;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private RoomService: RoomService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rooms$ = this.fetchAll();
    this.userId = this.authService.userId;
    this.authService.isUserLoggedIn$.subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = isLoggedIn;
    });
  }

  fetchAll(): Observable<Room[]> {
    return this.RoomService.fetchAll();
  }
}
```

room.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

import {Observable, throwError} from "rxjs";
import { catchError, first } from "rxjs/operators";

import { Room } from "../models/Room";
import { User } from "../models/User";
import { ErrorHandlerService } from "./error-handler.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RoomService {
  private url = "http://localhost:3000/room";

  httpOptions: { headers: HttpHeaders } = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService
  ) {}

fetchAll(): Observable<Room[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<Room[]>(this.url, { responseType: "json" })
    .pipe(
      tap((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }),
      catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError<Room[]>("fetchAll", []))
    );
}

  }
```

controllers/room.js:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const Room = require('../models/room');

exports.fetchAll = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const [allPosts] = await Room.fetchAll();
        res.status(200).json(allPosts);
    } catch (err) {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
    }
};
```

models/room.js:

```
const db = require('../util/database');

module.exports = class Room {
    constructor(topic, creator, player, stance, timeO) {
        this.topic = topic;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.player = player;
        this.stance = stance;
        this.timeO = timeO;
    }

    static fetchAll() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const connection = await db;
            let sql = `SELECT * FROM equals.rooms`;

            connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
                if (err){
                    reject(err)
                }else{
                    resolve(rows);
                }

            })
        })
    }   
};
```

I've tried using keyvalue and it just gives an error in the values spaces, the room in the rooms$ should be an object while the rooms$ should be an array. I originally though that maybe the sql server only having one room in it makes it return as an object instead of an array but it still errors out at that.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to fix it, despite to how the system was set up, it was returning a single object instead of array in the room.service.ts file, I will make the edit showing the correct fix